# Extjs buffered rendering in treegrid

Tags: extjs, treegrid, extjs6-classic

Is it possible to use buffered store for Ext JS (version 6) `TreeGrid`?. The parent node should be expanded to show all child nodes.

Comment: There is a difference between buffered stores and buffered rendering. Trees cannot use buffered stores. They can use buffered rendering (which is the default).

Comment: I having some 5000 records in hierarchy structure.initially i should load 10 records and while scrolling it should load remaining records in hierachy.

Comment: BTW. what is the difference between buffered store and buffered rendering?

Answer (score 1):

As Evan has mentioned, Trees cannot use *buffered stores*. This means what GSKT is asking for is not possible i.e. It is not possible to show first 10 records and then show the remaining records as you scroll.

However, when there are hundreds of nested records, what can be achieved is *buffered rendering*. This means that the child nodes at each level do not get into the DOM unless the parent is expanded. So, although there might be hundreds of records, they need not be loaded in the DOM unless the user actually wants to see them.

This is done by the following setting in the TreeStore:

```
lazyFill: true
```